# How to get the original handler URI (with wildcards, etc.) in a HandlerInterceptor in Spring?

Tags: spring

I am collecting custom metrics for my controller endpoints via `HandlerInterceptor`. In `postHandle` I have everything I need and I would like to save the metrics for my endpoints along with the original route defined in the controller, so not the actual route filled with the data.

E.g. I have `@GetMapping("/cats/{name}")` and make GET request on `/cats/tom` I still want the defined route `"cats/{name}"`

I found that I can do this with the `Object handler` which is the parameter of postHandle -> I can cast it to `HandlerMethod` get the annotations of the method and find it from `memberValues`. This seems a bit overkill I also have to filter for Get-, Post-, Put-, Delete-, Patch-, RequestMapping annotations. Is there any easier or more straightforward way to do this? If so how? If not what else do I have to take into consideration with this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Spring adds this data to the `HttpServletRequest` attributes. So it can be retrieved using:

```
String routePattern = (String) request.getAttribute("org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.bestMatchingPattern");
```